# Confusion about NSString mutability

Tags: objective-c

Using Xcode 9.x, Cocoa, and Objective-C.
I am new to Objective-C. I read in a tutorial that once a variable of type `NSString` is set, it can not get modified. But the following successfully changes the value of `s`. Not sure how to explain this. Maybe the documentation I was reading was too old and in Xcode 9.x things have been changed. Any comment please.

```
NSString *s = @"";
NSLog(@"%@",s); //works

s = @"Myname";
NSLog(@"%@",s); //works
```

Comment: You are not modifying the string. You are assigning a new string to the variable. Big difference.

Comment: If the string was a `NSMutableString` you could `append` additional strings to the end, for example, something you can’t do with `NSString`. You can only replace the whole `NSString` instance with another...

Comment: now it makes sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

@rmaddy already covered your case, but there's more into it.

`NSMutableString` happens to be subclass of `NSString`. If you have a `NSString*` passed as argument either in a method or property setter you cannot be sure if someone will not pass an actual `NSMutableString` instance which **does fullfil** the `NSString` contract. To guarantee the value is immutable you will often encounter an additional `[string copy]`. This ensures a local **immutable** copy is made and is guaranteed not to change.
Similarly Objective-C properties of `NSString*` type are as a good practice defined as

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* string;
```

This guarantees the same behavior.